# Any way to deliver data from google spreadsheets to clickhouse?

Tags: python, airflow, google-sheets-api, clickhouse

There is problem that our people fill every day in **google spreadsheet** some data and I need with a certain frequency (e.g. once a day) to send these tables in ***clickhouse***

(it located on our aws servers)

it doesn't matter whether *clickhouse writes only new data from tables or all tables every time*

please tell me a working method how to do it

from the Toolkit are **python**,can in theory work with ***sqlalchemy and airflow DAG***
but for the development of dag in airflow I have not yet found a guide how to write in python a script to **transfer data from googlespreadsheet**

the second option is with owox extension for google spreadsheet - but there you need to work with Google BigQuery, and this will breed a zoo, and I would not like to pay for BQ yet

Do you have any ideas how to use scripts to **upload tables to Clickhouse from google spreadsheets?**

Comment: For accesing your google spreadsheets I would suggest looking into [google's api documentation](https://console.developers.google.com/) or looking into the specifics of [sheets api documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api). Getting the data in any other way than through the google api will probably be messy.

Comment: the whole point of the question is how to do it step by step, it is clear that there is documentation, but a simpler way is desirable and not dancing with a tambourine and google api without best practice cases

Comment: I am afraid there is no simpeler way. Connection through an API is about as simple as it gets.

Also don't take sayings through a translator. I have no clue what dancing with a tambourine is meant to communicate.

Comment: consider using *curl* to get the required data by using [spreadsheets.get HTTP API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) and then pass the result to CH using [ClickHouse HTTP API](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/http/)

Comment: @vladimir but will the link (if created) to the Google table be indexed by search engines in this case? I read about the fact that this way anyone could go to view the information if you use http

Comment: @Nikita not if these docs are not public. You access them through secure API (it required authentication etc. - look at API endpoint description).

Comment: @vladimir Unfortunately, I anticipate problems with encoding using the POST curl method - the data will be difficult to digest
correct me if you think they won't need to be processed later
also - will the curl script work in dag python? Correct me if I'm wrong, but does airflow only perceive Python, or php too?

Comment: @vladimir - i searched python lib PYcurl - question is solved

Answer (score 1):

I found the Python library **pygsheets** - it is easier to access spreadsheets using the api than directly

official pygsheets dock - https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

in addition I found more libraries: **gspread and oauth2client** which can also be used to work on **Python with the api**
*step by step guide* https://towardsdatascience.com/accessing-google-spreadsheet-data-using-python-90a5bc214fd2
*official documentation for gspread* https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

than i can make dag at airflow and manage etl process

Comment: I just want to say that this is still using the Google API. It is simply a wrapper for the GSheets API.

Comment: eah - but, its more deeply and complex answer then simple: read google sheets documentation api

Comment: But your original question was, how can I use scripts to get data from google sheets. Not what is the best way or most simple way to achieve and work with google api data.

Also I recommend googling first before asking. Since you clearly found the answer rather quickly yourself.

Comment: there is a question-it is logical that we discuss the most effective and simple options for solving it:))
thank you for your participation